# Using iMacros to extract multiple combinations of a form to a CSV file

Tags: imacros

I'm brand new to iMacros, but I found the tool for a very specific use. However, I'm having trouble where to start..I think I'm a bit overwhelmed. Below is what I'd like to do, and I'll annotate it in English to explain the tasks, that I believe should be easy with the software..Any help in the right direction would be wonderful.

There are a lot of similar questions but like I said I'm brand new to the software and I imagine this should be straight-forward. Thanks!

```
VERSION BUILD=9002379
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=http://www.designashirt.com/QuickQuote.aspx
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:QuickQuote.aspx ATTR=NAME:listCategory CONTENT=%5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:QuickQuote.aspx ATTR=NAME:listType CONTENT=%27
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:QuickQuote.aspx ATTR=NAME:listProduct CONTENT=%31
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:IMAGE FORM=ACTION:QuickQuote.aspx ATTR=NAME:rptColors$ctl00$imgColorSwatch
'listFrontColors should cycle from 1 - 7
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:QuickQuote.aspx ATTR=NAME:listFrontColors CONTENT=%1
'listBackColors should cycle from 0 - 7
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:QuickQuote.aspx ATTR=NAME:listBackColors CONTENT=%0
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV FORM=ACTION:QuickQuote.aspx ATTR=ID:step3
'This input field should cycle from 6 - 300
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:QuickQuote.aspx ATTR=NAME:rptAdultSizes$ctl02$sizeBox$txtQuantity CONTENT=6
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV FORM=ACTION:QuickQuote.aspx ATTR=TXT:Hanes<SP>Tagless<SP>Tee<SP>DescriptionIt<SP>is<SP>easy<SP>to<SP>understand<SP>why<SP>Hanes<SP>is<SP>a<SP>go-to<SP>bran*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:QuickQuote.aspx ATTR=NAME:ddPrintType CONTENT=%SCRN
'This field is what needs to be extracted to a CSV file along with the listFrontColors & listBackColors & txtQuantity. example:
'  Front Back Price
'6    1    0   $15.94
'7    1    0   $15.xx
'...
'300  1    0   $xx.xx
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD FORM=ACTION:QuickQuote.aspx ATTR=TXT:$15.94
```

So far, I have:

```
VERSION BUILD=9002379
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET VAR1 {{LOOP1}}
ADD VAR1 +1
URL GOTO=http://www.designashirt.com/QuickQuote.aspx
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:QuickQuote.aspx ATTR=NAME:listCategory CONTENT=%5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:QuickQuote.aspx ATTR=NAME:listType CONTENT=%27
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:QuickQuote.aspx ATTR=NAME:listProduct CONTENT=%31
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:IMAGE FORM=ACTION:QuickQuote.aspx ATTR=NAME:rptColors$ctl00$imgColorSwatch
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:QuickQuote.aspx ATTR=NAME:listFrontColors CONTENT=%1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:QuickQuote.aspx ATTR=NAME:rptAdultSizes$ctl02$sizeBox$txtQuantity CONTENT={{!LOOP}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:QuickQuote.aspx ATTR=NAME:ddPrintType CONTENT=%SCRN
'POS=1 TYPE=TD FORM=ACTION:QuickQuote.aspx ATTR=TXT:$15.94
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV FORM=ACTION:QuickQuote.aspx ATTR=ID:quick-quote
TAG POS=17 TYPE=TD FORM=ACTION:QuickQuote.aspx ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Users\Jeff\ FILE=test.csv
```

Currently the output looks like this:

```
$0.00 
$0.00 
$0.00 
$0.00 
$0.00 
$15.94 
$14.59 
$13.58 
$12.80 
$12.17 
$11.66 
$0.00 
$0.00 
$0.00
```

I'm not sure why this breaks where 12 would be the number, but it does. If I can't automate the rest, I'd be fine with just editing this script and doing it ~90 times, still way easier, but not ideal.